# Call to Func<string,string> on razor is being ToString'ed instead of executed

Tags: c#, razor, func

Imagine I have this simple method:

```
public string A ( string key )
{
    return "_" + key + "_";
}
```

In the constructor of a class I say this:

```
public Func<string, string> F;

public AClass( )
{
    F = A;
}
```

In a controller I return the Func like this:

```
var a = new AClass();
ViewBag.MyFunc= a.F;
```

However, something like this in a view

```
@{
    var X = ViewBag.MyFunc;
}

// ...

<h1 class="whatever" style="float:left">@X ( "hello" )</h1>
```

means I get a ToString() on the F func rendered, instead of the actual method call I'd like to see, so instead of the output of the silly function A above, I see this

```
System.Func`2[System.String,System.String] ( "hello" )
```

Criticisms on why I should not be doing this are welcome, but what am I missing here? I think I am blind on something obvious.

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the spacing.

Try

```
<h1 class="whatever" style="float:left">@X("hello")</h1>
```

And if this still doesn't work, try this:

```
<h1 class="whatever" style="float:left">@(X("hello"))</h1>
```

Comment: I was thinking I really was missing something obvious, but not this. makes me want to shout some profanity. I need to see how this spacing was really that significant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space before the `(`, so that the Razor parser realizes that it's part of your `@` code.

Comment: This really was the lesson of the day. Thx,